# Laravel Blade without extra whitespace?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

If you do this you get an error:

```
<p>@if($foo)@if($bar)test@endif@endif</p>
```

And if you do this, you get `<p> test </p>`, adding too much whitepace:

```
<p>@if($foo) @if($bar)test@endif @endif</p>
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this appears to be getting a lot of search traffic so I figured I'd add an update to share how I'm handling this these days. Basically, it's a little more code but it ends up being stupid simple and very clean:

```
@if($foo)
  <p>Test</p>
@elseif($bar)
  <p>Test2</p>
@else
  <p>Test3</p>
@endif
```

The moral of the story is when you're working with blade, don't try to cram a lot of conditionals within elements. Rather, have the result of the conditional contain the element. It's clean, easy to read, and with only a few more characters spent.

Comment: I had this problem with my breadcrumbs, I wrapped them up in a `<span>`. Basically the same solution. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: While it pains me to resort to this approach (as there appears to be no alternative), it is surprisingly effective. Thank you!

Comment: @user151496 care to explain why?

Answer (score 46):

Try with a ternary operator, there is no whitespace control in Laravel

```
<p>{{ $foo ? ($bar ? 'test' : '') : ''}}</p>
```

Comment: Upvoted for alternate solution for the specific example.

Answer (score 14):

You can add `{{""}}` in between the code you want to close or connect without space.

```
<p>@if($foo)@if($bar)test@endif{{""}}@endif</p>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could always use the [hedronium/spaceless-blade](https://packagist.org/packages/hedronium/spaceless-blade) package on packagist to add this functionality to Blade.

Comment: aint working for `foreach loop`, still getting the spaces

Comment: The referenced package is designed to eliminate spaces in content between *already-parsed Blade directives*, not between *adjacent* directives with only whitespace between them. The link in Macin's Answer clarifies the distinction. This is the reason for which Symfony's Twig engine includes `{% spaceless %}` and `{% endspaceless %}`, despite the fact that its tag syntax employs opening *and* closing delimiters (`{%` and `%}`). In other words, the suggested solution addresses a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no `spaceless` tag in Blade.  If you want to use standard Blade tags you will have extra spaces. There is a [github discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4057) with proposal for new tag