# How can I remove spaces in view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I use laravel 5.3

My case is like this :

My code in view :

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    "
    @if(isset($country))
        {{ $country }}
    @endif
    @if(isset($city))
        @if(isset($country))
            -
        @endif
        {{ $city }}
    @endif
    "
</div>
```

The result like this :

> " England - London "

I want the result like this :

> "England - London"

How can I do it?

Comment: What's the difference between result and expectation ? Just spaces ?

Comment: @Sagar, Yes, it just spaces

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146045/laravel-blade-without-extra-whitespace

Comment: It might be due to double quotation in new line

Comment: @Sagar, I want `double quotation` also show

Comment: You have spaces at start and end or something else ?

Comment: @Sagar, No. I haven't spaces

Comment: try all code inside div in a single line, that may solve your problem ?

Comment: @Sagar, Yes, it solve. But the code becomes untidy

Comment: Sometime its happen :D :D

Comment: @Sagar, Is there no other way

Comment: I don't know why spaces are displayed ? May some other people here know . Best of luck

Comment: @Sagar, Yes. I had find the best answer

Comment: Congrats for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be the best method, but you could try setting the string to a variable and try the below code. Please verify whether the variable isn't containing spaces in your controller and send the trimmed variables to the view

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    {{--*/ $finalString = ""; /*--}}
    @if(isset($country))
        {{--*/ $finalstring .= $country; /*--}}
    @endif
    @if(isset($city))
        @if(isset($country))
            {{--*/ $finalString .= ' - '; /*--}}
        @endif
        {{--*/ $finalString .= $city; /*--}}
    @endif
    "{{ $finalString }}"
</div>
```

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231810/how-can-i-use-db-transaction-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the trim function of PHP?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <span>"</span>
    @if(isset($country))
        {{ $country }}
    @endif
    @if(isset($city))
        @if(isset($country))
            -
        @endif
        {{ $city }}
    @endif
    <span>"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same. I want the result : `"England - London"`. You try read my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@isset($country)
    @php($result = $country)
 @endisset
 @isset($city)
     @isset($country)
         @php($result .= '-')
     @endisset
         @php($result .= $city)
 @endisset
{{$result}}
```

Good luck!