# How can I use db transaction in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.3

I try this :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $product = $this->product_repository->find($id);
        $result = $product->categories()->detach();
        if($result) {
            list($status,$instance) = $this->product_repository->delete($id);
        }
        DB::commit();
        return ['status'=>true,'data'=>$status];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return ['status'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()];
    }
}
```

If the code executed, `$this->product_repository->delete($id)` not work / not success delete.

But this : `$product->categories()->detach();`, it works / success deleted.

How to if delete product failed, delete category also failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add `return` statement inside `transaction` that halts entire process and `DB::rollback()` is executed.

To switch the `return`, You can define a `boolean` variable and make `false` while you `catch` exception.

Like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $success = true;

    DB::beginTransaction();

    try{

        // Your Code

        $product = $this->product_repository->find($id);
        $result = $product->categories()->detach();

        if($result) {
            list($status,$instance) = $this->product_repository->delete($id);
        }

        DB::commit();

    }catch(\Exception $e){

        DB::rollback();

        $success = false;

    }

    if($success){
        // Return data for successful delete
    }

    else{
        // Return data for unsuccessful delete
    }
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: But why ?
`$sucess` will have value `true` if exception hasn't been caught which means no error in transaction so delete operation should be carried out

Comment: @TrendingNews Congrats

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
$returnResult = [];

DB::beginTransaction();

try {

    ...

    DB::commit();

    $returnResult['status'] = true;
    $returnResult['data'] = $status;
} catch (...) {

    ...

    DB::rollback();

    $returnResult['status'] = true;
    $returnResult['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}

return $returnResult;
```