# Remove whitespace from Laravel Blade dynamic page title

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I am using a layout file for each of my views. I am dynamically setting the page title from my controller methods like this:

```
$metadata = [
    'page_title' => 'My Page Title',
    'page_description' => null,
];

return view('foo.index', compact('metadata'));
```

Then in my layout file, I am doing this to render the title:

```
@if(request()->route()->getName() == 'welcome' || request()->route()->getName() == 'home')
    <title>Welcome!</title>
@else
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
@endif
```

The logic is working great, the titles are getting rendered correctly. However there is extra space in the `else` that I am having trouble removing. It is rendering like this:

```
            <title>    Dynamic Page Title
</title>
```

Ideally, it would render like this:

```
<title>Dynamic Page Title</title>
```

I have seen a [solution that others have provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146045/laravel-blade-without-extra-whitespace) but this does not seem to be resolving my issue (for some reason).

Because I am doing this in my `app.blade.php` file, I am not sure of another way to pass the variable up.

In each view, I am setting the title like this:

```
@section('title')
    {{ $metadata['page_title'] ?? 'Welcome' }}
@endsection
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the title as a second parameter to `@section` since it's the only content of the section

```php
@section('title', $metadata['page_title'] ?? 'Welcome')
```

> DO NOT CLOSE THE SECTION WITH @endsection

The white space is the new line and indentation of the section

Comment: Thank you so much!
I am curious though, by not using `@endsection` could that cause problems? For example, my `@section('content')` has an `@endsection`. The page blows up without.

Comment: Yes because you can have multiple sections in your view but passing the second argument instruct Blade to auto-close the section and an extra one would break the view